# Singleton class crashes

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton, c++14

Iv'e implemented a singleton class that looks something like this:

h file:

```
class MySingleton
{
public:
    static MySingleton& GetInstance();

private:
    MySingleton();
    virtual ~MySingleton();

    std::map<MyStruct, PointerToClass*, MyCompareStruct> mMyMap;
    CRITICAL_SECTION mMyMapCriticalSection;
};
```

cpp file:

```
MySingleton& MySingleton::GetInstance()
{
    static MySingleton instance;

    return instance;
}
```

On some runs my code crashes on the instance initialization:

```
    static MySingleton instance;
```

Am I doing something wrong in my implementation?
I'm working on visual studio 2015

Comment: Where does it crash ? What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: How do you specify if an instance has already created ? Did you take a look to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) ?

Comment: @cromod static will be initialized only once, so that functions is correct. I think the problem might be at the constructor of a singleton.

Comment: it crashes on the first line of GetInstance: "static MySingleton instance;"

Comment: This is the crash from windbg: (790.2f74): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
MySingletonDll!MySingleton::GetInstance+0x34:
00007ffa`dfd86fe4 488b0cca        mov     rcx,qword ptr [rdx+rcx*8] ds:00000000`00000048=????????????????

Comment: @rosl What's the implementation of your constructor?

Comment: MySingleton::MySingleton()
{
 InitializeCriticalSection(&mMyMapCriticalSection);
}
 
}

Comment: There isn't enough here to work with.

Comment: Just an aside - singletons are typically viewed as an anti-pattern since they're glorified globals and, as such, make the program innately globally stateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's likely to crash is the 'std::map' initialization before stdlib is fully initialized.

This would happen if your `GetInstance()` is called from another static initializer. The order of initialization is not defined between different libraries.

The solution is to not construct non-POD things before main is called.

Comment: I think that's my problem. I use the GetInstance in a static function that might be called very early. How do you recommend fixing the issue?